# Virtualbox - Oracle Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, virtualbox, listener

I have just installed Virtualbox and executed official Oracle Image (Database App Development VM).

1. I can of course open SQL developer within the guest OS and connect to DB.
2. I can connect to DB from host OS with SQL Developer.

I set up the network interface to bridged and:

3. I can also connect to DB from other (than host) computer within my home network.

I also have static external IP, I did the port forwarding and appropriate firewall rules on router as well as I turned of Windows Firewall on host OS. But when I try to connect from outside my local network, I get the error **Oracle Network Adapter could not establish the connection** - even when I try to connect from host OS using external IP.
Below I attach my Listener.ora contents. I checked that oracle listener is running. I run out of ideas, anyone can help?

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orclcdb)
      (SID_NAME = orclcdb)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.56)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

#HOSTNAME by pluggable not working rstriction or configuration error.
DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (orclcdb)
```

Comment: in visualbox network , you need to use bridged adapter to allow host on local area network to communicate with database

Comment: please check out the following link, https://geek-university.com/oracle-virtualbox/configure-bridged-networks/

Answer (score 0):

> "But when I try to connect from outside my local network"

That's because your home network is not "routable".  Read more [here][1], but I'll quote the salient part:

> Class C: Any address that starts with 192.168
>
> All routers will discard any traffic to a private network address.
> That means that it is entirely private. Anything you send on your own
> network will never get out to the Internet. Anything that comes in
> from the Internet will not be sent onto your local network.

Personally, I would not want it to be any other way.  Why do you think you need to reach this vm from outside your home network?
[1]: https://www.quora.com/What-does-192-mean-in-an-IP-addresses-and-What-is-it